# linq to xml CDATA problem

Tags: xml, linq, cdata

When I used linq to retrieve xml, `<CDATA[[` `]]>` is removed, which is what I want to achieve.

But when I save the file, `<CDATA[[`  `]]>` becomes  `&lt;CDATA[[` `]]&gt;` in the xml file.
Whether or not I explicitly append with `<CDATA[[`  `]]>` before saving gives me the same result.

Tried appending with `&lt;CDATA[[` `]]&gt;` but still gives me the same result.
Is there any other way to make it show `<CDATA[[` `]]>` in the xml file?

I'm using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` to write to the file after saving the `XDocument` using `XDocument.Save(System.IO.StringWriter)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

not 100% sure what you are asking here, but it seems to be how do I create a CData section in your XElement. It's actually very simple just use the XCData object.

```
yourXElement.Add(new XElement("SomeNode", new XCData("Some CData content")));
```

When you are reading it, as you already see, you don't need to do anything special, the cast operator overload will extract the data for you i.e.

```
string myCdata = (string)xe.Element("SomeNode");
```

Comment: u give some idea, but Im not really sure how to apply. Show some example of the code below, replaced some sensitive words.Anyway in the node, I have some attribute that sld stay same.
var abc= (from def in XDocument.Descendants("someNode")
                                                                select new
                                                                {
                                                                    def
                                                                }).First();


abc.def.SetValue("<![CDATA[<TextBlock Text=\"" + data + "\"/>]]>");

Comment: sorry for the messy comment, but im not sure how to make comment to go new line

Comment: dunno if it helps C_Range but this fixed my problem ... thx :) +1